# Change App's Launch Images, with out re-submitting to store; Possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I was wondering if its possible to change my applications launch images with out having to go through the lengthy submission process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe but probably not.

If the images are contained in the app themselves then no, you have to submit a new binary to apple for aproval. However, if your app was downloading the launch images from a server you could simply change the images on the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. An app bundle is subject for approval, not the executable per se. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at all with the iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

I think you app could show an image you save in the NSUserDefaults, for example. After it's started the app could check if a newer image is available on the web server. You can try this, i'm not sure it will be approved by apple. Just try and write there if they approved your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Your launch image is `Default.png`, which is packaged with the binary into an app. The whole thing needs to go through the process.